# How to make a onepager?

Tags: layout

I have a bit of a problem creating a one page template. I'm half way there, I get stuck with the menu links. Here is what I do, I'm using Helix Ultimate:

1- create the required rows in the template
I gave them the id's #sp-about and #sp-contact

2- create the menu links for about/contact as external urls #sp-about and #sp-contact.

3- create the custom html modules for about and contact
Assign them module positions (user1 and user2).

So far, so good. Now the problems:

If I want to use the homepage, I have to set home to external url, and set about and contact as sublinks under it. Joomla does not allow external url's on the component. I have to set an article or category, and that looks plain ugly.

If I set another menu link, say Company with About and Contact under it: Company is not the component, so I can link it to external url. I set it to #. Nothing shows up. In the module manager external urls are grayed out.

I'm doing something wrong, but have no idea what.

Comment: are you familiar with developing Custom extension with Joomla!? Or you plan to do it without coding.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea but why not disable the menu and create a custom html component for the menu instead. Switch these out and you can do what you like.

Or where the menu placeholder is located in the template just hard code the menu in. Hope this helps